# Returning to beginning of file after getline

Tags: c++

So i've read all the lines from a file thusly

```
while (getline(ifile,line))
    {
        // logic
    }
```

Where ifile is an ifstream and line is a string

My problem is I now want to use getline over again, and seem to be unable to return to the beginning of the file, as running

```
cout << getline(ifile,line);
```

Will return 0

I've attempted to use:

```
ifile.seekg (0, ios::beg);
```

To no avail, it seems to have no effect. How do I go back to the start of the file?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Since you have reached (and attempted to read past) the end of the file, the `eof` and `fail` flags will be set. You need to clear them using `ifile.clear` – *then* try seeking:

```
ifile.clear();
ifile.seekg(0);
```

Comment: Just as a sidenote, In C++11, seekg clears the eofbit flag, if set before the call.

Comment: I can't find any reference to the standard, but the proof is in the pudding so to speak.  Using gcc9.2 and compiling with the c++17 standard will not actually induce the stream to start from the beginning, unless clear() is called before seekg().  Perhaps it is an implementation bug in gcc?

Comment: Read one more character and it [fails](https://godbolt.org/z/KjK4Y7).  Again, I'm not sure if this is some artifact of the implementation, but it appears that if you read past what is available in the stream (from a file or a string object or any other stream object), you need to call clear before seekg will work as described.

Comment: @Onofog Right, my code was completely unrelated. In fact, C++11 didn’t change the relevant semantics and *my answer was wrong*. The code still clears the `eofbit`, as per the specification. But that isn’t sufficient, since the `failbit` is *also* set once we read past the end of the file (which is what the last iteration of the `while(getline(…))` loop does.

Answer (score 12):

This is because the eof flag has been set on the stream - due to you reaching the end of the file.  so you have to clear this as an additional step.

Eg

```
ifile.clear();
ifile.seekg (0, ios::beg);
```

Answer (score 2):

FYI: In my case, the order DID matter, thus

1. clear
2. seek

otherwise the next getline operation failed (MSVC v120)