# How to go back to the beginning of a file after reaching .eof() in C++?

Tags: c++

I just tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343173/returning-to-beginning-of-file-after-getline), but don't work, maybe because I'm reading character by character?

```
char character;

while (!file.eof()) {

    character = file.get();
    cout << character;

}
```

Comment: Your code has a defect in it. `file.eof()` is only meaningful **after** an attempt to read. You should rewrite your code as follows: `while(file.get(character)) { cout << character << endl; }` it is simpler and easier to get correct this way.

Comment: Tomalak, sorry, I'm Chilean, my English is not good. Evan, thanks for the advice ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it works. The trick is call

```
file.clear();
file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
```

just after the iteration. Sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

Did you try [the accepted answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343173/returning-to-beginning-of-file-after-getline/5343199#5343199)  The call to `clear` is the key.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is a stream (data piped in from another program) then you will not be able to seek.

Comment: I guess the author assumes seek-able file. :)