# Reading a text file from the first line multiple times (C++)

Tags: c++, file, iostream, getline

I'm using "getline" to read some lines in a text file. It works as it should, but I'm calling the method multiple times.

```
while(getline(file, line))
{
    //Do something
}

//More code in between

while(getline(file, line))
{
    //Do something else
}
```

The problem is that when I call "getline" the second time it starts reading from where it previously finished (e.g. If the first while loop ends at the second line then the next loop starts at the third line). How can I ensure that my program reads the file from the first line every time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343173/returning-to-beginning-of-file-after-getline

Comment: Why do you do that? Why not keep the line once you read it? Anyway, the answer is in the thread that Yann4 linked.

Comment: This will send you back to the beginning: `file.clear(); file.seekg(0);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need that same first line multiple times I think you should reconsider your strategy.

1. Just read the line once.
2. Save it in a variable (or just keep it in the variable "line" you already have).
3. Close the file.

You would avoid a lot of not necessary I/O operations...

Nonetheless as other people suggested if by any reason you want to procede with this approach you need to insert:

```
myinputstream.clear();             //clear the buffer
myinputstream.seekg(0, ios::beg);  //reset the reading position to beginning
```

between each attempt to read the same file.
And do not forget to close it eventually.

```
myinputstream.close();
```

Comment: What if he has a massive file and needs to find different lines for different reasons at different times?

Comment: Question is clearly asked so it should be comment, not the answear.

Comment: @Xarylem: in markdown used on the site, when you want ordered list, write dot (`.`) after each number instead of `-`.

Answer (score 3):

There's a seekg() function that should help 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/

```
 iostream::seekg (0, iostream::beg);
```

will move you at the beggining of the stream

Comment: I think you may also need to clear the stream's error flags first in some cases.

Comment: Sure, User should remeber that error flags will not be reset by itself.

Comment: sometimes we open a file for read while another process is opening it for writing... this is why we update by opening it more than once. yes sure we move to the beginning of the file after each read because the end of read means reaching EOF. so: myinputstream.clear();             //clear the buffer
    myinputstream.seekg(0, ios::beg);  //reset the reading position to beginning