# How to pass fstream to a function multiple times

Tags: c++

I am struggling with a programming assignment in my C++ class.  The assignment involves creating a random access file to store inventory for a hardware store.  I can create, read and write to the file just fine.  I have a function which opens the file or creates a new one if it does not exist. This function then returns the open file as std::fstream.  I am trying to pass that open file to another function which prints out the contents of the file to the console. When I call the print function the first time it works just fine. However, when I return to the main menu and try and call the print function again, it prints out nothing from the file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "HardwareData.h"

void printMenu();
unsigned short int getMenuChoice();
std::string getFileName();
std::fstream openFile(const std::string& fileName);
std::fstream newFile(const std::string& filename);
void printHeader();
void printAllRecords(std::fstream& file);
void newRecord(std::fstream& file);
unsigned int getRecordNum(const std::string& prompt);
bool recordIsBlank(std::fstream& file, unsigned int recordNum);

int main() {

    unsigned short int menuChoice{0};
    std::string filename;
    std::fstream file;

    while(menuChoice != 6){
        printMenu();
        menuChoice = getMenuChoice();
        switch(menuChoice){
            case 1:
                filename = getFileName();
                file = openFile(filename);
                break;
            case 2:
                printAllRecords(file);
                break;
            case 3:
                newRecord(file);
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return(0);
}

std::string getFileName(){

    std::string filename;

    std::cout << "Enter a filename:";
    std::cin >> filename;

    return filename;
}

std::fstream openFile(const std::string& filename){

    std::fstream file{filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary};

    if(!file){
        std::cout << "File could not be opened." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Creating new file." << std::endl;
        file = newFile(filename);
        std::cout << "Successfully created " << filename << std::endl;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << filename << " opened successfully" << std::endl;
    }

    return file;
}

std::fstream newFile(const std::string& filename){

    std::ofstream file{filename, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary};

    if(!file){
        std::cerr << "File could not be created." << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    HardwareData emptyRecord;

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&emptyRecord), sizeof(HardwareData));
    }
    file.close();

    return openFile(filename);
}

void printHeader(){
    std::cout << "Record#    Tool Name         Quantity        Cost \n";
    std::cout << "==================================================\n";

}

void printAllRecords(std::fstream& file){

    file.seekg(0);

    HardwareData record;
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&record), sizeof(HardwareData));

    printHeader();
    while(!file.eof()){
        if(record.getRecordNum() != 0){
            record.printRecord();
        }
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&record), sizeof(HardwareData));
    }
}
```

I was expecting to pass the file by reference and still be able to use that reference again on another function call. I am not getting any errors

Comment: If you read to the end of the file you need to reset it to the beginning and clear the error from hitting EOF before you can continue to use it.

Comment: Thank you!
Based on your suggestion, I found this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343173/returning-to-beginning-of-file-after-getline

So I used: 
file.clear();
file.seekg(o, std::ios::beg);

It seems to work well.  Would that be an appropriate solution?

Comment: Yes! Or you can open the file multiple times and use each stream independently. (But there's a fairly small limit to open file handles, so beware of that solution.)

Comment: [Be wary of `while(!file.eof())`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons) You have avoided one of its nastier effects, but more than just eof can happen to block reading.

Comment: There is a difference between keeping a file open vs. open a file on demand and close it when you're done with reading/writing. I usually prefer the latter as the file is safely processed after closing (or I got an error and know that it failed) even if my appl. crashs later. Additionally, number of concurrent file handles supported by OS is a lesser issue in this case. In opposition, keeping a file open might be done to block other applications for concurrent access. MS seems to do so in their Office appl.s (may be with additional options in open) but I don't like this feature very much...

Comment: See [How to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Show definition for `HardwareData`