# Authentication for password not working using an external txt file

Tags: c++, codeblocks

My external text file, contains usernames and passwords in the form:

```
username1
password1
username2
password2
```

It isn't comparing the password inputted to the password in the file for some reason. Here's the code:

```
    userdata.open("userdata.txt");
    while(getline(userdata, temp))
    {
        counter++;
        if(counter % 2 == 1)
        {
            usernames.push_back(temp);
        }
    }
    cout<<"Please enter your username: ";
    cin>>username;
    for(int i = 0; i < usernames.size(); i++)
    {
        if(username == usernames[i])
        {
            usernameMatch = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    while(usernameMatch == false)
    {
        cout<<"\nInvalid Login! Please re-input your username: ";
        cin>>username;
        for(int i = 0; i < usernames.size(); i++)
        {
            if(username == usernames[i])
            {
                usernameMatch = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    while(getline(userdata, temp))
    {
        counter++;
        if(counter % 2 == 0)
        {
            passwords.push_back(temp);
        }
    }
    cout<<"\nPlease enter your password: ";
    cin>>password;
    for(int i = 0; i < passwords.size(); i++)
    {
        if(password == passwords[i])
        {
            passwordMatch = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    while(passwordMatch == false)
    {
        cout<<"\nInvalid Login! Please re-input your password: ";
        cin>>password;
        for(int i = 0; i < passwords.size(); i++)
        {
            if(password == passwords[i])
            {
                passwordMatch = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"\nLogin Successful!"<<endl;
        userdata.close();
```

The username checker works, but the password checker part doesn't and just keeps on returning the "`Invalid Login! Please re-input your password:`" when I'm putting in the correct password.

I'm new here so please tell me if I missed anything out. Also, I can only use the libraries included since we haven't learnt any others other than `ctype.h`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: If you want your program to work the way you've written it, you'll need to do something like this ([Returning to beginning of file after getline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5343173/2602718)) before reading passwords. It seems you just assume the `userdata` fstream will just reset to the beginning of the file for you (which it won't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately we don't have all the relevant code.  Based on what you've provided, I'd assume that `temp`, `username` and `password` are all `string` and that `usernames` and `passwords` are `vector<string>`.

#### First potential problems

First check that you have explicitely initialized `counter=0`.  If you forgot that initialization, it's a random gamble.

Then, if your `username` or your `password` could contain a <kbd>space</kbd>, your `cin>>xxx` would be out of sync, since it would consider this as two different inputs. So, if the rule is one entry per line, read with `getline(cin, xxx)`

#### Serious issue in the way you read your file

You intend to read first your while file to filter out the usernames on the odd lines, then you read again the file to filter out the passwords on the even lines. But:

- Your while-loop exits with the stream `userdata` on error:  whatever you do, you will not be able to read anything until you [`userdata.clear()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) the error
- Anyway, you do never rewind your file rewind.  So the `getline` will fail even after clearing the errors because you'd still be positioned at the end of the file.  So you'd need to [`userdata.seekg(0);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) to rewind.
- Finally, you never reset the counter to 0.  So your odd/even check will fail if the number of lines of the file is odd (and empty line at the end is sufficient to make this happen.

A much easier approach would be to read the file in one pass without rewind:

```
while(getline(userdata, temp))
{
    counter++;
    if(counter % 2 == 1)    // if odd 
    {
        usernames.push_back(temp);
    }
    else                    // if even
    {
        passwords.push_back(temp);
    } 
}
```

#### And to finish, a security breach :-)

First you check if one of the user matches the username. Ok. Then you check if the password matches **a** password, **any** password in the file,  not necessarily the password corresponding to the username:

- This means that a legitimate user could impersonate any other user of the system without knowing their password !!
- Worse:  if any user has a weak password, it's the full system that is can be compromised !!!

The right way is to find the user, keep its index (this means that i should be defined outside of the loop) and after the password is entered, you cjeck if the password matches the password at the **same index**.

Now, asking for the username and telling that the usename does not match before asking the password makes the work for a hacker, since it's immediately clear what data is wrong.

The right way to do this check is to ask username AND password, and then make the verification and just tell that the login is invalid (so a potential intruder doesn't know if it's the username or the password or both that are wrong):

```
cout<<"Please enter your username: ";
getline(cin,username);
cout<<"\nPlease enter your password: ";
getline(cin,password);
for(int i = 0; i < usernames.size(); i++)
{
    if(username == usernames[i])
    {
        usernameMatch = true;
        passwordMatch = (password == passwords[i]);
        break;
    }
}
while (!usernameMatch || !passwordMatch) 
...
```

Comment: Thanks, @Christophe. I haven't learned in class how to rewind a file so the second suggestion was also a big help. After I posted I did realize the counter error and I realized that the reason the password error message happened was that nothing was stored in the password vector. Also, my teacher did say to try to focus on security, but he talked much more about password encryption so I never realized the security breach. In all, thanks!