# C++ while(file input stream) loop executes only once in the superior while loop

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, fstream, stringstream

So basically, I have a text file and a dictionary file. I want to compare every word in dictionary, to every word in text file.

```
while (getline(mainFile, line))
{
    istringstream lineStream(line);

    while (lineStream >> word1)
    {
        ToLower(word1);
        int len1 = word1.length();

        while(dictFile >> word2)
        {
            ToLower(word2);
            int len2 = word2.length();

            if (len2 == len1)
            {
                //...

                if (word2 == word1)
                {
                    //....
                }

        }

    }

}
```

The problem is with "while(dictFile >> word2)" loop. It executes perfectly for the mainFile's first word but totally ignores the dictFile loop after that.

Sorry for the messy code I tried to trim it so you can understand what's going on. And this is my first question here, forgive if I made any mistakes.

Comment: I think this is what you need:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5343199/14629267)

Comment: If the duplicate doesn't answer your question please provide a [mre]

Comment: Yes this solved my problem. Thank you so much!