# unable to get return data from class in .hpp file

Tags: c++, string, vector, include

I have 2 files: main.cpp and parser.hpp

I am returning vector<vector> from a member function in class in parser.hpp. However it seems I am not getting anything in my main.cpp from the return value because when I print its size I get 0.
This is my main.cpp:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "parser.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream file;
    file.open("test.csv");
    csv obj;
    obj.parse(file);
    obj.print_parsed_csv(file);

    vector<vector<string>> parsed_csv_data = obj.parse(file);
    cout << parsed_csv_data.();
    cout << parsed_csv_data.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < parsed_csv_data.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < parsed_csv_data[i].size(); j++)
            cout << parsed_csv_data[i][j] << '\t';
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

This is my parser.hpp

```
using namespace std;

class csv
{
public:
    vector<vector<string>> parse(ifstream &file)
    {
        string str;
        vector<vector<string>> parsed_data;
        while (getline(file, str))
        {
            vector<string> parsed_line;
            while (!str.empty())
            {
                int delimiter_pos = str.find(',');
                string word = str.substr(0, delimiter_pos);
                // cout << word << " ";

                if (delimiter_pos == -1)
                {
                    parsed_line.push_back(word);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    str = str.substr(delimiter_pos + 1);
                    // cout << str << endl;
                    parsed_line.push_back(word);
                }
            }
            parsed_data.push_back(parsed_line);
        }
        return parsed_data;
    }

    void print_parsed_csv(ifstream &file)
    {
        vector<vector<string>> parsed_csv_data = parse(file);
        cout << parsed_csv_data.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < parsed_csv_data.size(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < parsed_csv_data[i].size(); j++)
                cout << parsed_csv_data[i][j] << '\t';
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
};
```

I am getting correct cout output in parse() only. print_parsed_csv() in parser.hpp and the cout in main.cpp both are giving 0 as the variable's size.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time you call `obj.parse` the stream object is read from until you get to the end of the file. You need to either reopen the file or reset `file` to point back to the beginning of the file after reading from it.

You pass the same `file` variable to each of the three functions below but only the first one works. The first call to `obj.parse` moves where `file` is pointing in the input file. When `obj.parse` exits the first time, `file` is pointing to the end of the file so when it's used in the subsequent 2 calls, there's nothing to read.

```cpp
    obj.parse(file);  // <-- this works fine
    obj.print_parsed_csv(file);  // <-- this fails

    vector<vector<string>> parsed_csv_data = obj.parse(file);fails
                                          // ^^^^^^^^^- this fails
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343173/returning-to-beginning-of-file-after-getline) for answers on how to reset the `ifstream` to the beginning of the file.

Comment: the problem is in return part. I am not getting anything in return. so naturally nothing goes on to the arguments i pass on to the next functions. could you help me find a solution to this?

Comment: @Krushnal Patel No, the problem is there's nothing to read because you've "used up" the file stream. See edited answer for clarification.