# Can't read ifstream after counting number of lines using istreambuf_iterator

Tags: c++

In the current working directory, I have two files: `test.cpp` and `test.dat`. The file `test.cpp` contains the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::ifstream file("test.dat");

  std::cout << &file << '\n';

  // const std::size_t line_count = static_cast<std::size_t>(std::count(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), '\n'));
  // std::cout << line_count << '\n';

  std::cout << &file << '\n';
  std::cout << "good? " << file.good() << '\n';
  std::cout << "bad? " << file.bad() << '\n';
  std::cout << "fail? " << file.fail() << '\n';
  std::cout << "open? " << file.is_open() << '\n';
  std::cout << "rdstate " << file.rdstate() << '\n';

  // file = std::ifstream("test.dat");

  std::cout << &file << '\n';

  std::string line;

  while (std::getline(file, line)) {
    std::cout << line << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The contents of `test.dat` is

```
This is
a test.
123
```

Now, if I compile `test.cpp` with

```
clang++ test.cpp -o test
```

and then run it, I get the following expected output (most importantly note the last three lines, which are the contents of `test.dat`):

```
0x16b0c70a8
0x16b0c70a8
good? 1
bad? 0
fail? 0
open? 1
rdstate 0
0x16b0c70a8
This is
a test.
123
```

This is all fine and good. The part that I don't understand is that if I now uncomment the two lines in `test.cpp`

```
const std::size_t line_count = static_cast<std::size_t>(std::count(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), '\n'));
std::cout << line_count << '\n';
```

the output is now

```
0x16d3d70a8
3
0x16d3d70a8
good? 1
bad? 0
fail? 0
open? 1
rdstate 0
0x16d3d70a8
```

Note that the line count (3) is computed correctly, but now the actual contents of the file are missing.

If I then uncomment the line

```
file = std::ifstream("test.dat");
```

the output is what I expect (line count and file contents)

```
0x16b3ff0a8
3
0x16b3ff0a8
good? 1
bad? 0
fail? 0
open? 1
rdstate 0
0x16b3ff0a8
This is
a test.
123
```

The behaviour is the same with `g++`.

It seems that reading the number of lines with `istreambuf_iterator` somehow messes up with the file stream, but how? What is going on here? My guess is that after counting the lines the `istreambuf_iterator` is at the end of the file. If this is the case, is there a way to 'reset' the file back without reassigning it like I have done here?

---

For completeness, here are the versions of `clang` and `gcc`:

```
> clang++ --version
Homebrew clang version 17.0.4
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin
> g++ --version
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I'm on macOS Sonoma 14.1

Comment: Check out cppreference.com, this is working according to the spec.

Comment: Why do you keep printing the address of `file`?  The location of the variable hasn't changed and usually once is enough.

Answer (score 1):

When you uncomment your `istreambuf_iterator` code, you are actually consuming the `ifstream`'s data, so there is nothing left for the `getline` loop to read afterwards. Before you can read the data again, you need to either:

- seek the `ifstream` back to the beginning of the data.
- close and re-open the `ifstream`.

Answer (score 0):

When the uncommented lines are executed, this expression is consuming the content of the `ifstream`:

```cpp
std::count(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), '\n')
```

So, after that, the `file` `ifstream` variable is pointing to the end of the file, and you don't have any other data to process.

You need to either reset the position to the start of file, or reopen it again.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5343199/3444205), to reset the file pointer position, adding the following code before the while would make your program work:

```cpp
file.seekg(0); 
while (std::getline(file, line)) {
    std::cout << line << '\n';
}
```

See [cppreference for seekg](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg).

But ideally, you just need to count the number of lines breaks while you read and put each line from the input to the output for what you seem to want to achieve.

May I ask why don't you just compute the number of lines in the while?:

```cpp
  size_t line_count = 0;
  while (std::getline(file, line)) {
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
    line_count++;
  }
```